# ios Repeat alarm on every monday

Tags: objective-c

How to repeat alarm on every MONDAY ?

If I am set an alarm today at 12:00 PM how to repeat the alarm on every monday at 12:00 PM.

Can any one give a solution for this?

I am using `UNUsernotification` for setting the alarm.

Comment: **NSCalendarUnitMonth**.  set like this property    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMonth;

Comment: How to change the code below  ?                           UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:dateComponents repeats:YES];

Comment: post ur code ... then only we can helps u what u tried...?

Comment: see this link:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/